# Cakephp 3.0 $query->toArray();

Tags: associative-array, cakephp-3.0

Hey I am trying to find a solution  I am retrieving the data from mysql using this command :

```
$meals = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$query = $meals
->find()
->select(['id' ,'username'])
->where(['role' => 'patient']);
 $data = $query->toArray();
```

This is my code  after using query->toarray()  I am getting this value

```
 { "id": 4, "username": "s2" }
```

I want to put this value in my form which is like this :

```
   echo $this->Form->input('user_id', [
        'options' => [1 => 'Admin', 2 => 'Author']
    ]) ;
```

How to use foreach to get value as id and usernmae as name any quick solution

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find('list')`

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users')
    ->find('list', ['valueField' => 'username'])
    ->select(['id' ,'username'])
    ->where(['role' => 'patient']);

$this->set('users', $users);

echo $this->Form->input('user_id', [
    'options' => $users
]);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs

Comment: hey jose I have some issue I am trying to add a hidden input can you suggest me in this where d_id I want to update this column here uer_id get updated but in hidden form it is not doing any action