# cakephp3.0 query Builder Retrieve data

Tags: query-builder, cakephp-3.0

Hey I am facing some problem  I am trying to create a patientcontroller.php in which I want to get data for only one user id from users table so that I can create a dashboard for sngle patient here is my code :

PatientsController.php

```
 <?php 


 namespace App\Controller;

 use App\Controller\AppController;
 use Cake\Event\Event;
 use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
 use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
 class PatientsController extends AppController
 { 


     public function isAuthorized($user)
 {
  return true;

   }

  public function index (){

 echo $this->Auth->user('id');
 $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
 $users->find('all')->where(['id' => 4]);
 $this->set('users', $users);
 }
```

I want to get username bio and profile information in my Index.ctp I am trying to pass data using query builder but I am confused so any help

Comment: One very very important tip for you: Learn the basics. Really. Understand them. It will help you in the long run. In your case that means: Use BAKE, seriously, use the bake plugin to bake your code, that will output VALID best practice code you can learn from for the future. What you are currently doing is guessing probably. That ain't helping you, and even if we did it would only last for a few hours tops. If you want to finish your project in a reasonable time frame, I highly recommend doing what experienced (core) devs tell you. Please :) We have been there and we know what we talk about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found A solution for this  query : Full code for this kind of problem :
PatientsController.php

```
<?php 
   namespace App\Controller;
   use App\Controller\AppController;
   use Cake\Event\Event;
   use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
   use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

   class PatientsController extends AppController { 
       public function isAuthorized($user) {
           return true;
       }

       public function index () {
          $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
          $articles = TableRegistry::get('Users');
          $query = $articles->find()
              ->where(['id' => $id]);

          $this->set(compact('query'));
       }
    }
```

For Index.ctp

```
 <!-- File: src/Template/Articles/index.ctp  (edit links added) -->

  <h1>Patient Dashboard</h1>
  I am patient

  <?php  
  foreach ($query as $row) {
     echo $row->username ,$row->password;
  }
  ?>
```

This kind of solution is veryhelpful if you are just trying to move from procedural php to oops in cakephp .

Comment: then make give it a correct answer bro I can not correct my own anser

Comment: I honestly meant that this was the correct answer and that I'm happy you could figure it out

Answer (score 3):

So you have a number of issues with both your approach, techniques and also your code.

**Methods**
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html
If you want to get a single patients record, you should be using the `view()` method in your controller. So you need to create a new method called `view()`, in which you can return your record. This method should, in most cases, take an id as the parameter.

**Tables**
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html
In CakePHP the table which is associated with the controller will be loaded by default. So there is no need to use the `TableRegistry` to load the table.

**Fetching data**
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html
When you are looking for a single record you have two choices. You can either just use a find, with a `first()`.

```
$this->Patients->find()
   ->where(['id' => $id])
   ->first();
```

Or you can use `get()` which will throw an exception if a record isn't found.

```
$this->Patients->get($id);
```

**Joining associated data**
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html
If you want to join data to your user, then you'll need Tables to manage that data, which can then be contained, using foreign keys in your database. This will change your finds, to include a `contain()` call.

```
$this->Patients->find()
   ->where(['id' => $id])
   ->contain(['Profiles])
   ->first();
```

**Outputting data in the view**
You can set the result of your find to the view as you have done, and then you can loop through, or output it how you like, using the variable you've set. In your case `$user`.

**Summary**
So overall you can see that there is quite a bit you are missing. Hopefully this will help get you on track.

Comment: I am using a users table based on roles one for patient and one for doctors so after login I am redirecting patient to patient index page and their I want to get data of user id through which  I will associate other tables so I am using table registry for users model and then I want to find username and other details in index view so that I can create users profile

Comment: So you should be using the `UsersController::view()` method. A single item is accessed through a `view()` method in most cases, as an index is a list of items.

Comment: I want to make it simple  so dependency must be avoided my approach is very simple using tableregistry I am getting users model now I need to just add simple query select username and all where id = an id through which user is login and I want to put that data into index method my code is very simple and almost correct but I am asking in my approach and code what I am doing wrong .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362318/cakephp-3-0-query-toarray/29363014#29363014 Here I have done that but same thing not happening

Comment: Simplicity is admirable, but in fact you are making your application much more complex, by breaking convention. You seem to lack a basic grasp of how CakePHP works and it's conventions. This is why you are struggling.

Comment: ya I am knew to cakephp I am trying to create a simple procedural type of code into cakephp  . So there must be a simplicity in code structure . This is a problem only because it has very simple  tutorials and no such examples like creating a general search function full example is needed documentation should be very easy and full with examples like search and others

Comment: The documentation is exemplary. Tutorials are provided. If you want someone to write your code for you, that's not the job of the documentation. I would recommend looking at the bake plugin for automated code generation. https://github.com/cakephp/bake
Or check YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/user/CakePHP

Comment: There are lots of people like me who want to learn cakephp but these type  of query which must be in documentation this will help cakephp to move faster in every php framework codeigniter and laravel has very good documentation and there are some resources where we can learn from scratch

Comment: Bake some code and read it, that's the best advice I can give you, again.

Comment: I want to print built SQL after

$this->Patients->find()
   ->where(['id' => $id])
   ->contain(['Profiles])
   ->first();
echo $query ? I want the syntax from i can show that query

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is basically your third question here asking for exactly the same thing (getting the results of a query) I will point you to these very useful resources that you should read:

The tutorials: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html

They basically have everything you need to understand how queries work and how they can be used in the view and forms.

The ORM manual: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html

You will find plenty examples of getting data and using it after retrieving it.

Comment: ya I know there are lots of examples but in this code   echo $this->Auth->user('id');
  $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
     $users->find();
 
  $this->set('users', $users);

Comment: I am unable to get any data based on query builder I am using $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');      $users->find();

Comment: Please it is a very simple question you will get reputation